# Sharepoint 2007 - slow site with low number of records

Tags: 2007, form

On Sharepoint server 2007, we have a service request site with 9000 records in it.

Clicking a new request can take 25 seconds before the blank form opens which seems very slow to say the least.
Everything else about the site is fast.
Looking at the alluserdata table in sql server shows that the table contains lists from another site. In all there are 115000 records in this table.

If I do a select * from alluserdata, it takes 30 seconds to run. There are over 100 fields with no data in them. This, looking at raw data, is really bad.

Is there anything we can do to speed things up?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked into paging?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, it is always a bad idea to look directly into the SQL tables that power SharePoint as it can stunt your growth, cause sterility, blindness and hair loss (well, that is the impression that MS gives about it anyway)

However, this almost sounds like you are using either an underpowered SharePoint server or an underpowered SQL server so it would be a good idea to start monitoring certain key items on both, like average CPU, disk IO, Disk paging, etc.. Given your comment about how long the query took to run on the database itself, that would probably be the best place to start looking.

If this is a standalone server that is running both SharePoint and the SQL server then odds are very high that the box is severely underpowered.  That was fairly common for SharePoint 2007.  You would really be better served in that case by moving SQL to a different server, though this is not a trivial task.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your thoughts - and I thought that I was bald because of my Dad :)